# “cannot open” when trying to save screen recording in quicktime player

Tags: screen-capture, quicktime

After choosing a file location to save a screen recording, the movie will start to save, then it says "Cannot Open" and nothing is saved. I can retry but it still doesn't. I just saved a video before this. It's on macOS High Sierra. 10.13.1. This same issue is plastered all over the Apple.com help forums but there are no answers.

QuickTime is Version 10.4 (928.5.1) - the version that came with my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016).

After the saving progress bar gets to about 1/4, it flashes "cannot open this media may be damaged quicktime" then "Cannot Open"

I'll add a video below to show exactly what

To debug, I did confirm that a 5 second video with voiceover could save. However, a 25 minute video will not. I closed that video and recorded another screen recording for 10 minutes long and same issue. In the past I've been able to record 10-30 minute videos and save. Now it only allows small videos.

[image]

Video of what happens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBME45Ks3_o

[image]

Comment: How much space is left on your hard drive?

Comment: @daviewales 100GB

Comment: Well it's not that then!

Comment: This is a bit of a longshot, but there are a couple of things you can try to isolate issues like this. Try starting in 'Safe Mode', by holding down Shift-S on boot. This disables unnecessary kernel extensions, and a few other things. Then try the screen recording. If it works in Safe Mode, but not in normal mode, then we can start to do some investigation to find the problem. If that doesn't work, try creating a new user account on your Mac, and see if the screen recording works in the other account.

Comment: Did you manage to try my answer?

Comment: I found that ONE OF POSSIBLY MANY root causes of this issue is **after turning screen recording back on, duplicating and trimming a different unsaved screen recording video.**  Workaround: 1) save the video after recording 2) duplicate and save the duplicate 3) trim.  This may be very prevalent because A) who wants to save a giant untrimmed screen recording and B) who wants to trim anything without duplicating it first.

Comment: I've only tried this once, but I noticed there was sort of glitching in the recording that I couldn't save, and it made me wonder if the processing got overloaded when I was recording it. So I figured maybe if you make the window smaller when you are recording, sure you'll have a video with smaller dimensions, but maybe the recording process can handle it more easily. I tried it with my next video and it worked ok, but like I said, not properly tested. Just an idea of something to try in future..

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions problem. If it’s a bug I suspect it will be fixed in a future macOS update. Not much help, I know.

Until then, you have to peek behind the curtain:

1. Unsaved recordings are stored at `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Autosave Information/`
2. The file will be called `Unsaved QuickTime Player Document.qtpxcomposition`, or similar
3. `Show Package Contents` on that file
4. Inside is `Screen Recording.mov` which you can copy and keep

[image]

Comment: I was able to "save" the recording using this trick however whenever I try to open or convert the MOV file from the package it throws errors. I've tried QuickTime, iMovie, VLC, Adobe Media Encoder...while I can play the MOV without issue in Quicktime, I can't use it anywhere without things exploding. This makes me think maybe the reason it couldn't save is that there is something in the file data or the file headers that's gone sideways.

Comment: I've never encountered that before. Can you reproduce it consistently with new, unsaved screen recordings?

Comment: Haven't really tested it or what might've triggered it; pretty salty about it and already spent hours just trying to recover things. I was able to rename the MOV file to use an AVI extension and open the AVI in QuickTime, let it "convert", save as MOV and it worked minus the last ten minutes which are missing video but have audio. I think somehow the video got corrupt, but again haven't tested.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It works great. Saved me a lot of hassle.

Comment: Thanks, @MattSephton! You saved me from a certain heart attack.

Comment: @MattSephton thank you! You saved my life. QuickTime player never worked so well for me but at least now I can get my recordings from it. I wonder if they will fix this saving issue soon. ( I am on Mac OS Mojave)

Comment: @MattSephton  I don't have a `Containers` folder in my library. Mac OS 10.13.4 High Sierra.  I also can't seem to find `com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX`.  Would this be anywhere else?

Comment: The file path is very different on my Mac than in this answer. But I was able to get the file. I searched `"com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX"` and found a quicktime `Document` (_icon wasn't a folder though_). I double-clicked that file and saw my `.mov` file in there. I then dragged the `.mov` file onto my desktop and saved it in a folder.  This answered it for me.

Comment: @Chris22 would be great if you could post your path

Comment: @MattSephton You should be given a million points for this.

Comment: @LexJacobs exactly as in my answer

Comment: @MichaelThompson I had the same issue. But in my 2 hour video, the last 3/4 of video was all gone. Thankfully the video wasn't so important, but it was still a bummer.

Comment: You saved my life dude! Thank you so much, tho the last 10 mins or so was gone :(

Comment: @MattSephton you are a F&@#*((! hero man. Seriously saved me from just losing 90 minutes of important footage. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

Had this situation now, couldn't locate the temporary file in the suggested places - however:

Doing Menus:

`File/Move To...` - did the trick, to the `~/Documents` folder

Answer (score 0):

I've got a friend who had a similar sounding problem. In his case it was Docker could not write to a temporary location. He had tried the permissions repair a couple different ways.

He was able to resolve his problem using a bit of what I call *Apple Black Magic* which is [resetting your NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and [resetting your SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295), which seems to have influence over features you would have never thought were associated.

These two seemingly unrelated resets, seems to resolve many IO based bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to save the file using [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr).

As a shortcut I was running the following command in the Terminal to create a simlink into ~/Downloads:

`ln ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Autosave\ Information/Unsaved\ QuickTime\ Player\ Document.qtpxcomposition/Movie\ Recording.mov ~/Downloads/rec.mov`

Then I used HandBrake to create a lower resolution export.
The shortcut saves the need to navigate into this complicated original location. When export is finished, the simlink should be deleted (e.g. `rm ~/Downloads/rec.mov`)

**Warning:** be careful not to exit QuickTime before you are finishing the export!